# How I can calculate if time is more than one minute in dajngo?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am working on django rest APIs where I have to expire a random generated code after one minute. But I am having problem that how I can check weather the time is more than one minute? Thanks in advance for your addition in my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two `datetime` objects, just subtract them from one another and call the `total_seconds()` method on the resulting `timedelta` object.

```
if (dt2 - dt1).total_seconds() >= 60:
   print("Expired!")
```